# Is it possible to use a temp table in a data flow source?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a data flow in a 2012 SSIS package where I'm trying to use a temp table as the data source.  I'm using an OLE DB data source with a SQL Command Data access mode.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Checksums (DBName sysname, CheckSum bigint)
-- Code that loads the Checksum table here
SELECT DBName, CheckSum FROM #Checksums
```

In order to get the data source to pull the list of columns I temporarily put the following:

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS sysname) DBName, CAST(NULL as bigint) CheckSum
```

That got the columns created and I was able to map to my destination.

I have `ValidateExternalMetadata` set to false on the data source and `DelayValidation` set to true on the data flow.

My code works correctly in SSMS however every time I run the package it errors out with the following:

```
[OLE DB Source [39]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid object name '#qtemp'.".
[OLE DB Source [39]] Error: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020204A.
```

Is it possible to use a temp table like this in a data source?  If so is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: Are you setting the **RetainSameConnection** on the `Connection Manager` to `TRUE`? See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat

Comment: @RLF I'm doing this in a loop hitting multiple servers will that affect this?

Comment: @KennethFisher Sorry, I have never tried to hit multiple servers in a loop from SSIS. It seems logically possible to have an outer SSIS package call a sub SSIS-package that would connect to and retain a connection for a single server, then close that connection.  But it is over my SSIS head.

Comment: @RLF I've done the inner/outer package thing but prefer to use expressions to change the server name of the connection manager in a for each loop.  I'll give the other a shot.  Maybe since it's change server names that will force a connection change at the appropriate time.

Comment: @KennethFisher Jaime Thomson (SSIS Junkie) shows [Using temporary tables](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/11/19/SSIS_3A00_-Using-temporary-tables.aspx) as well as [on SE - How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6160015/1387418)

Answer (score 3):

These steps helped me:

1. Write the final result set into a table.
2. Script that table as CREATE into a new New Query Editor Window.
3. Remove everything except the open and close brackets that define the columns.
4. Wrap that into another pair of brackets.
5. Recompose the calling of your SP from

   ```
   exec p_MySPWithTempTables ?, ?
   ```

into

```
exec p_MySPWithTempTables ?, ? with result sets
(
    (
        ColumnA int,
        ColumnB varchar(10),
        ColumnC datetime
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The temp table will confuse SSIS.
To get around the issue, write your code like this:

```
Use Database
Begin
    Exec('Create Table ##Table(Field Integer)') With Result Sets None;
    Exec('Select Field From ##Table') With Result Sets
    ((
        Field Integer
    ));
End
```

This allows the use of the temp table and provides the metadata to SSIS.

Comment: Dropping local temporary tables is handled automatically when they go out of scope, but you are suggesting a global temporary table, and the behaviour is different for those. So perhaps this will resolve the OP's issue, but won't it introduce another one?

Comment: Please explain "confuse". What is confusing and why is it "confusing"?

Comment: @AndriyM The global temp table will drop automatically when the last session which has an open transaction on that table will disconnect. In the SSIS scenario that most often means after the package is executed. So Chris's solution is fine.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It might confuse SSIS since it is saved on a server in tempdb database, see my answer here. If you now loop over many servers, as the questioner tells us, you need to call the connection of the right server again before you write to the temporary table. But that is not how temporary tables are meant to be, they should rather work like CTE:s, staying in the same server, and you would not need to care about the connection when you save to a temporary table. I am just guessing this, it might be one thing out of many.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I would offer another solution that I have found helpful not just in SSIS, but in Management Studio Import Wizard, PowerPivot, etc..  If you don't need to index your temp table, you could always use table variables instead.  As long as you use the "set nocount on" hint at the beginning, you should be able to use this in your SSIS data flow source.  Your new code should look something like this...

```
set nocount on

declare @Checksums table (DBName sysname, CheckSum bigint)
--Code that loads the Checksum table here
select DBName, CheckSum from @Checksums
```

Comment: As long as you're executing all your code in a single SQL batch (and thus, in a single SSIS task), this is true. With a temporary table, in theory, if you set **RetainSameConnection** to true, then you can use a temp table in separate SSIS tasks.

Comment: @RDFozz Right. See also [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631010/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-ssis-control-flow-task-and-then-use-it-in-dat).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to deal with variables, stored procedures or other workarounds. Take the "tempdb" system database as the connection and set the "RetainSameConnection" connection property to `True`. All of your temporary tables are saved in that "tempdb" system database, and you cannot change it.

See a guide on this with many screenshots at [How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in data flow task? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196761/11154841).

SSIS can reach temporary tables on "tempdb" and deal with these tables as if they were not temporary. The temporary tables stay alive until the run stops or you stop the debugging, see [How to see temp table created by code in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21440753/11154841). You can choose them as a normal destination or source in the editor while you are still planning if you create them during your SSIS work.